# How to add surface texture to a OBJ. File

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects

I'm really new to Blender and what I'm trying to do is upload a OBJ file from Fusion 360 into Blender and then, physically distort the surface to add a cast metal texture to the surface and then export that model as an STL for 3D printing. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: My understanding of texture in Blender is that it is an optical illusion, not a physical distortion of the surface. If your goal is to have a surface irregularity, Blender texture is not the correct approach.

Comment: Are you trying to color the object or deform it? Blender materials can do both, but if you want to export the deformation effect you should use a displacement modifier instead.

Comment: Trying to physically deform it